# Why ManagementObjectSearcher call is insanely slow (30sec-2mins)

Tags: c#, wmi

I know it's hard to reproduce this problem, but maybe I'm doing some silly mistake here

but how can I improve performance of this call?

I already use cache for it, but maybe there's some smarter way because atm it take 2min on my machine and around 30sec on server and in both cases it's way too long in my opinion

```
public (bool Success, string Version) GetSomeVersion()
{
    //return(true, "1.6.2");
    var data = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Vendor = 'ABC' AND Name LIKE 'ABC%'").Get();

    ManagementBaseObject found = null;

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        found = item;
        break;
    }

    if (found == null)
    {
        return (false, "");
    }

    return (true, found.GetPropertyValue("Version").ToString());
}
```

Comment: I know it's not an especially satisfactory answer, but it is the truth ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen haha, sorry, I added those dots to meet characters requirement :P Generally going via Registry seems to work fine and fast